# Inline jquery script to a separate js file with asp.net master pages

Tags: asp.net, jquery, master-pages

Hai guys,
         How to include inline jquery scripts used in an aspx to a separate js file with asp.net master pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your masterpage can have a script link to the core Jquery file:

```
<html>
<head runat="server" >
    <title>Master page title</title>
    //link to Jquery script
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="Head" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
.
<asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" />
.
</body>
```

ASPX page can have other script links specific to the page only

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" Runat="Server">
    //other scripts specific to this page only
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.abc.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>
```